# Is Pandas FIPPA compliant?

Tags: security, permissions, data-protection

I am interested to know what kind of access privileges are possible when using Pandas. Of course Pandas packages are trust-worthy, but for people with FIPPA protected data in their files, is there any way that data can be read by anyone other than the user calling the package?

Again, this isn't about malicious attacks, just about what permissions exist that I might not be aware of when calling Pandas.

Thanks!

I've tried...
Articles. The documentation. SME's...

Comment: Pandas is just a tool for manipulating data. It can create, write and read files but it does not provide security features, it is not its role, it is just backing on the Operating System.
It is up to the user to ensure the way it is used is secure.

Comment: This wasn't quite what I meant. Like Outlook e-mail add-ins where there is a third-party who owns the software and has access privileges to your e-mail, I wonder if the owner of Python package software could have access privileges to my files.